# Excel, Advanced Filter Multiple Criteria (And, Contains) Not Working

Tags: excel

I am using Excel Advanced Filter and it is not working Not Working. Please see my below data that I am working with. The Data is my List Range and the Criteria is my Criteria Range in the advanced filter. The filter is not working since it including: Req Approver 1 Decision, Req Approver 1 Decision Date. I do not want those included in the output data set. Please help. I am new to using advanced filters in excel.

Data

```
    Original Name
    Req Approver 1 Decision
    Req Approver 1 Decision Date
    Req Approver 1 Decision Comments
    Req Approver 1 First Name
    Requisition
```

Criteria

```
Original Name
*Req Approver*
*First Name*
```

Comment: I just want to see: Req Approver 1 First Name. So, I want to filter by contains 'Req Approver'  then by contains 'First Name'.

Comment: No, I need to know how to do multiple filters in excel for contains. I have no idea how to do this in excel. So, I would like to first filter by contains Req Approver and then filter by contains First Name. Sometimes I may need to filter by contains 3 or more criteria words. So I need to know how to do it this way. Thanks!

Comment: I solved it, please see my below solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution using advanced filter.

Criteria

```
Original Name      Original Name
*Req Approver*     *First Name*
```

Excel Advanced filter can work with AND as well as OR logic depending on how you set up the criteria range:

Criteria on the same row are joined with an AND operator.

Criteria on different rows are joined with an OR operator.

More information:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/09/07/excel-advanced-filter/#criteria-range